# Loading internal files over ssl/https

Tags: http, google-chrome, ssl, https

I am having a serious issue.. I am trying to load a page over https and it fails. chrome says something like 'the page at ... ran an insecure content from http:www.mysite...'

Firefox doesn't give this error but the issue is that even if I force https on my page.. the css/js/images that I am including in the page are loading over http for some reason.. when I run that on local version (my machine) and make a page https.. it includes all css/js/images over https as well.. but when I do the same over live site.. it doesn't use https and hence the erros..

All my includes are relative and I am not including any file using http://

I am totally lost.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but was able to solve it by first testing the connection (if it is secure or not):

```
$protocol = 'http://';
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    $protocol = 'https://';
}
```

And then before every include add this instead of protocol:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $protocol; ?>url.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```